# Sublime Text 2 - get command pallete typed text

Tags: python, plugins, event-handling, sublimetext2

I am operating on the [Sublime Files](https://github.com/al63/SublimeFiles) plugin, and wanted to capture the text that is typed once you enter the command palette (I press control+command+N).

I looked at the [API reference](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html).

Hoping that 3 would also work for Sublime Text 2 (not sure). The text that is typed is used to filter the selection of the current directory, so I figured that text would be stored somewhere. I couldn't find it.

I turned to the API reference and tried on_modified and on_activated randomly, that didn't work. I tried to get this working for a couple hours and searched the web for solutions or help, couldn't find much (maybe I wasn't looking hard enough?)

What I am looking for is a way to capture the text typed into the command palette so that I can enhance the plugin for my needs. For example, given a directory named foo containing files bar baz boo - I'd see a list in the form of /path/to/foo, bar, baz, boo and if I typed in "ba", I would like to be able to capture that "ba"

I am running on OS X Mavericks.

Please let me know if there is more information I can supply to make it easier to understand my request.

Thanks!